# Is Kubernetes Networking Smart Enough to Route ClusterIP Requests to Local Pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-networking

I think the question has most of the information.  If I have a Service that is a ClusterIP Service, and a Pod accesses that Service, since the load balancing is built into the routing table, are the routing rules smart enough to prefer traffic to the local Node?  Is there a way to configure it so that the traffic does prefer (or even be forced) to go to the local Node?

Reasoning - I'm thinking about running a caching server as a DaemonSet, which makes sense if traffic is likely to go to a local Pod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[internalTrafficPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#internal-traffic-policy) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect - thanks!  I missed that one.  It's sad that there isn't a "local preferred" option, though.  As it says it drops traffic if there isn't a local option.

Comment: As an update to this - a beta feature has been added called "topology aware hints" which enable all sorts of topology-aware routing of requests.  The discussion doesn't specifically mention local traffic but I believe it is included.  In any case, this is enabled by adding the notation "service.kubernetes.io/topology-aware-hints" and setting it to "auto".  The documentation is at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/topology-aware-hints/